# Create an algorithm that arranges them in order to form the largest possible integer

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I am struggling with this coding problem in Java. It has to be solved using an algorithm. It is supposed to give me the largest possible inter that can be formed with the numbers in the array: {10, 7, 76, 415}. I tried to solve it using selection sort. So far I have is this code below but it's giving me the wrong output. My code:

public class largestNumber {
public static int largestNumber(int[] arr) {

```
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length -1; i++) {
        for (int j = i +1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            String temp1 = Integer.toString(i) + Integer.toString(j);
            String temp2 = Integer.toString(j) + Integer.toString(i);
            
            if (Integer.parseInt(temp2) > Integer.parseInt(temp1)) {
                int swap = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = swap;
            }
        }

    
    }
    
    String ansNum = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ansNum += Integer.toString(arr[i]);
        
    }
    
    return Integer.parseInt(ansNum);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    int [] arr = {10, 7, 76, 415};
    int output = largestNumber(arr);
    System.out.println(output); //Print out the number
}
```

}

The given output from this code is:10415767
But the right answer is: 77641510

Please give your feedback and thoughts.

Comment: So, for the input array {10, 7, 76, 415}, is the answer supposed to be 77,641,510?  Because you can get bigger than an int pretty quick.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what the problem that your code is supposed to be solving is, or what your code currently does which is different to that.

Comment: But as a 'first guess' at what's wrong.  You're `return`-ing a `String` from a method which says it will return an `int`.

Comment: You also need to fix the swap code. You need a temp variable.

Comment: Just to clarify why a 'temp variable' is needed, this is because when you do `arr[i] = arr[j];` you have now _changed_ `arr[i]` and it is equal to `arr[j]`.  So when you _then_ do `arr[j] = arr[i]` you are using the new value, and nothing changes.  `tmp = arr[i]; arr[i] = arr[j]; arr[j] = tmp;` avoids this issue.

Comment: Edit: I just updated the code the it's compiling now. But it's giving me wrong output

Comment: I think the algorithmic approach is even simpler: You can just sort them in descending order by their leading characters, and then the second characters, etc. Mismatched lengths would compare the last character they could (so `73` < `7` < `79`). The end result will be the biggest possible number (digit-wise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix the bugs** as shown below and it should work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { //correction here
        for (int j = i +1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                String temp1 = Integer.toString(arr[i]) + Integer.toString(arr[j]); //correction here
                String temp2 = Integer.toString(arr[j]) + Integer.toString(arr[i]); //correction here
```

To write some **elegant code**, I would have used a comparator as shown below:

```
        String[] stringArr = new String[arr.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            stringArr[i] = String.valueOf(arr[i]);
    
        Comparator<String> comp = new Comparator<String>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(String str1, String str2){
                String s1 = str1 + str2;
                String s2 = str2 + str1;
                return s2.compareTo(s1);
            }
         };
        
        Arrays.sort(stringArr, comp);
    
        String ansNum = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) {
            ansNum += stringArr[i];
            
        }
        
        return Integer.parseInt(ansNum);
```

To talk about **time complexity**, the two for loops in your code makes this solution `O(n^2)` whereas with the use of sort it becomes `O(nlog(n))` where `n` is the number of elements in the input array. So, not only the code becomes elegant with the use of comparator, in this case it becomes efficient too.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class largestNumber { 
  public static int largestNumber(int[] arr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length -1; i++) {
        for (int j = i +1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            String temp1 = Integer.toString(arr[i]) + Integer.toString(arr[j]);
            String temp2 = Integer.toString(arr[j]) + Integer.toString(arr[i]);//rectified
            
            if (Integer.parseInt(temp2) > Integer.parseInt(temp1)) {
                int swap = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = swap;
            }
        }

    
    }
    
    String ansNum = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ansNum += Integer.toString(arr[i]);
        
    }
    
    return Integer.parseInt(ansNum);

}
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        int [] arr = {10, 7, 76, 415};
        int output = largestNumber(arr);
        System.out.println(output); //Print out the number
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally of little use, as it provides no explanation of why this particular code works. Try to add an explanation.